# How to setup Codeigniter 3.1.11 on Windows IIS Server without any errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis

I installed Codeigniter on a Windows IIS Server. I have also installed and enabled all the required extensions according to the Codeigniter Documentation. Please check the error code logs below and help me resolve it. Thanks in advance

```
  INFO - 2023-05-18 18:57:38 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2023-05-18 18:57:38 --> Hooks Class Initialized
ERROR - 2023-05-18 18:57:38 --> Severity: Warning --> include_once(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\hooks./../libraries/App_modules.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\hooks\InitModules.php 12
ERROR - 2023-05-18 18:57:38 --> Severity: Warning --> include_once(): Failed opening 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\hooks./../libraries/App_modules.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\hooks\InitModules.php 12
ERROR - 2023-05-18 18:57:38 --> Severity: Warning --> include_once(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\hooks./../../system/helpers/directory_helper.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\hooks\InitModules.php 14
ERROR - 2023-05-18 18:57:38 --> Severity: Warning --> include_once(): Failed opening 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\hooks./../../system/helpers/directory_helper.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\hooks\InitModules.php 14
ERROR - 2023-05-18 18:57:38 --> Severity: error --> Exception: Class "App_modules" not found C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\hooks\InitModules.php 16
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting File Permissions in Windows with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851821/setting-file-permissions-in-windows-with-php)