# mkdir(): Permission denied in Yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, iis-8.5

After installing yii2, I got the following error.

[image]

Some suggests that I should give full permissions to IIS_IUSRS but still to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't need to set the permissions to `777`, that is a security problem as it gives read and write access to the world.
 It may be that your apache user does not have `read/write permissions` on the directory.

If you use Ubuntu do this :

Make sure all files are owned by the Apache group and user. In Ubuntu it is the `www-data` group and user

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/webserver/www
```

Next enabled all members of the `www-data` group to read and write files

```
chmod -R g+rw /path/to/webserver/www
```

The php `mkdir() function` should now work without returning errors

Comment: I am using IIS.

Comment: @beginner : take a look here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089368/php-mkdir-permission-denied-running-on-windows-server-2008-iis-7-due-to-read-onl