# Yii2 framework error

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, yii2

I'm new with  framework and recently, i install yii2  on my computer, but then when i'm trying to test the frontend of yii2, it show this error. This is my first time using this, so i didn't know what is really the error is.

[image]

So, anybody can tell me what should i do to fixed the error and make the framework run on my computer successfully.

Comment: if you don't want to answer, just leave it be. I know i'm stupid because i'm new.that why i'm asking.. but do it really need to downvote other people question?..i'm here to learn.

Comment: You may want to refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539915/mkdir-permission-denied-in-yii2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enter command line `chmod -R 777 runtime` in your folder where the framework itself is located. If you use an extended application, then in the root of the project it will be so `сhmod -R 777 frontend/runtime`

Answer (score 2):

You have a problems with permissions. The runtime directory should have permissions set to 0777