# php - "mkdir" function on window server- iis

Tags: php

I'm using "mkdir" function in order to create folder. it's working fine on my Linux server. but when i upload my project to a windows/iis server (where i installed Apache) the function "mkdir" not function.

```
$file_root = '../files/company-name';

if (!file_exists($file_root)) {
    mkdir($file_root, 0777, true);
}
```

I heard something about the path structure ("/", "\") but i'm not sure...

Comment: The Windows equivalent of `makedir` is `md`.

Comment: @IvanRubinson those commands have nothing to do with using PHP to create a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user that the webserver runs as, likely has no permissions to write in any of the directories under the web site (or server) root. You'd have to grant the right permissions to that user.

Comment: OK, but when we talking about website - who is the user (in the server point of view)?

Comment: On my Linux server it's working fine. On my windows/IIS server (where i installed Apache) it's not working

Comment: check this if it will help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089368/php-mkdir-permission-denied-
running-on-windows-server-2008-iis-7-due-to-read-onl